# Find the value of the partial derivative.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Find the value of the derivative
$$\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^m\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^n\left\{\dfrac{1}{z[a^2+(b+z)^2]}\right\}~=~?$$where $~z^2=r+sx^2+ty^2~$ and $~r,~s,~t,~a,~b~$ are constants.

**What I am doing so far :** I made step by step partial differentiation with respect to $~x,~y~$ respectively and trying to find some symmetry. So that it can be extended up to $~m^{\text{th}}~$and$~n^{\text{th}}~$order. But failed to do so. Also it is a lengthy process too. So I want your help to solve it.

Thank you in advance for spending your valuable time with it.

Comment: Where did you find this partial differential equation? What is the context?

Comment: There is nothing in my hand. I got the problem from a page in internet(I lost  the link). But it seems interesting to me, so I am trying to solve it. But I was stuck. I have no further knowledge, how to overcome.